# Reducing false negative and confidence improvement in wake-word detection

Tags: deep-learning, speech, wake

so am working on a custom wake-word detection using mycroft-precise. So i have around 385 wake-word and 1064 not-wake-word data, so to make the data balance, I used 3x augmentation (slow, fast, noise overlap) on the wake-word data. The test result of that was good but false negative was close to 20% though and the confidence of precise-listen was not satisfactory. SO I removed the augmented data and made not-wake-word data close to equal to wake-word and trained with the same parameters, the test results were bad. It will be very helpful if anyone can help me to figure out how to reduce false negative and improve the confidence of the precise-listen (precise-listen is a command where u say the wake-word in real time and if it gets activated, a confidence is shown as output).

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: We are using mycroft precise (https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-precise)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!!
Please describe your question in more detail with more insights like explaining the actual task you want to accomplish, add you erroneous code snippet and what all resolutions you actually tried already to eradicate the issue
Make note to add corresponding tags and format your code before pasting here.
For more details visit StackOverflow's guidelines.